# Connecting Roland A-01K to Mixer

Tags: mixing

I just bought a Roland A-01k because I like the chiptuned sounds it makes, and I want to connect it to my mixer. Problem is, there's only a headphones jack! I tried connecting it like a line in device, but it's too quiet. When I connect it as a mic in, it works, but I have to boost the gain so much that it hisses. How do I get a clean sound into my mixer?

Answer (score 2):

Plug headphones into the output.  Do they work?  If so, I think the problem is with the cable you are using between the A-01k and your mixer.   You need a stereo mini-jack leading to TWO normal jack plugs (or whatever your mixer takes).  If there's any stereo information in the A-01k output, connect to TWO channels of your mixes, panned hard R and hard L.  If not, you can use just one, ignoring the other.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the manual, not sure if this is what should be connecting to the mixer. This looks like a device that would connect to a keyboard, then you would connect the keyboard to the mixer. Not sure why you would want to connect a MIDI or DAW controller directly to a mixing board.

Comment: It has a built-in synth that I really like. So it does actually make sounds I can record.